# Boost program_options parsing enum bitmask

Tags: c++, boost

My program has a set of recoverable errors that can occur, let's call them `ErrorA`, `ErrorB` and `ErrorC`. For any of these errors, my program can either ignore them (as they are recoverable), or terminate, the latter being the default behaviour. Now I want users to specify if any of these errors should be ignored instead. This should happen through a command line parameter `--ignore`, which is followed by the names of the errors that shall be ignored. For example:

```
./MyProgram --ignore ErrorA ErrorC
```

Within the code, I represent these error categories using a single bitmask enum:

```
enum class IgnoreErrors {
  None = 0, //Ignore no errors
  ErrorA = 1 << 0,
  ErrorB = 1 << 1,
  ErrorC = 1 << 2
};
```

I am using `boost::program_options` and trying to add the `--ignore` option to the `options_description` like so:

```
value<IgnoreErrors>()->multitoken()->default_value(IgnoreErrors::None)
```

This requires that I provide an implementation of `operator>>` for `IgnoreErrors`, and this is where I got stuck. I tried this:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, IgnoreErrors& err) {
  //Assumption: 'in' contains ALL tokens passed to the --ignore flag
  err = IgnoreErrors::None; //Needed to make |= work

  string token;
  while(getline(in, token, ' ')) {
    err |= ignore_error_from_str(token);    
  }

  return in;
}
```

This correctly parses one or more tokens into a single `IgnoreErrors` value, however after that my program fails with: `the argument ('ErrorA ErrorC') for option '--ignore' is invalid`. Interestingly enough, if I do `in >> token` instead of `getline`, I only ever get the first token (`ErrorA`).

If I change the implementation of `operator>>` to parse a single token into a single `IgnoreError` value and change my `options_description` to use `value<vector<IgnoreErrors>>()`, Boost doesn't recognize the `operator>>` for `IgnoreErrors` anymore and instead looks for an implementation for `vector<IgnoreErrors>`. Which I could provide, however then I have to manually fold this vector into a single `IgnoreErrors` value, which seems weird. I want to understand what the 'intended' way to handle this situation is.

How can I parse a multitoken argument as a single value using `boost::program_options`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to make this work that seems reasonable. Instead of providing `operator>>`, a [custom validator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#idp523621680) can be used, like so:

```
void validate(boost::any &v, const std::vector<std::string> &all_tokens,
              IgnoreErrors *target_type, int) {
  validators::check_first_occurrence(v);
  std::vector<std::string> tokens;
  boost::algorithm::split(tokens,
                          validators::get_single_string(all_tokens),
                          boost::is_any_of(" "));

  auto ignore_errors = IgnoreErrors::None;

  for (auto &token : tokens) {
    ignore_errors |= ignore_error_from_str(token);
  }

  v = boost::any(ignore_errors);
}
```

Some things that were not so obvious to me:

- The result of `validators::get_single_string(all_tokens)` in my example is `"ErrorA ErrorC"`, so I had to split this string up into multiple tokens manually
- The specialization of the `validate` function has to be in the same namespace as the type that it is specialized for (`IgnoreErrors` in my case)